# Visual representation for JSON Patch

Tags: json-patch, rfc6902

I've developed a tool which creates JSON patch results in a .csv file specifying differences between two sets of JSON files.

I want the business side of my organisation to be able to easily interpret this data and wondered if there is a UI or Graphical library that I can readily use to accomplish this. I've tried searching but cannot find anything in existence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convert it to a useable web-front they can access, if it's to be kept secret make them log-in for it.